# What do we want to ask Get Fit Guy?

Tags: discussion, blog, site-promotion

We're going to be interviewing [Get Fit Guy](http://getfitguy.quickanddirtytips.com/) of [Quick and Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/) prior to being mentioned in his podcast. This will be happening pretty soon, so now we need some questions! The top-voted questions will be selected, and then a blog post will be made about the interview. The post will give him something interesting to refer his listeners to.

For ideas, check out this [English meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/what-are-we-going-to-ask-grammar-girl) where we did a similar thing with [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/). Feel free to suggest your favorite Fitness & Nutrition question that you'd like to get his take on!

Note - we're doing the same thing with [Nutrition Diva](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/what-do-we-want-to-ask-nutrition-diva) of Quick and Dirty Tips, but I'm asking for suggestions separately since they will be two separate interviews.

Comment: Is there a particular audience that is being targeted? I feel like there is a big difference between experts and novices, and right now I'm coming up with questions more for novices.

Comment: @MattChan I think your questions are appropriate. It seems like his podcast/blog topics are targeted toward people who just want to exercise, rather than experts (e.g. "Does yoga burn calories" and "What to eat before and after exercising").

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things I would also ask Get Fit Guy in addition to Ivo's answer.

- What are some of the most common fitness myths, misinformation, and stereotypes regarding fitness and exercise?
- Why do you think these myths and misinformation exist? What can people do to prevent the spreading of such bad information?
- What do you recommend for people who have no fitness experience start with for exercise?

  - Should they go to the gym to "work out" and "get fit" using weights or running on a treadmill?
  - What other options are there besides a gym where people don't have to feel self-conscious about being unfit?
- What are characteristics of things (people, places, equipment, costs, industries, etc.) to avoid when starting to exercise and get fit?

  - **Note:** No need to name names, be specific, or endorse here if these become a litigious issue.
- Why do you think some people who say they want to get fit fail to commit to exercise?

Comment: This question about [making the gym less intimidating](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/any-trick-to-make-going-to-the-gym-less-intimidating) is a good one.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the first question should be how they got started with writing about this stuff professionally

Comment: Agree, as well as what their background & expertise is. My first reaction to these interviews was "who?" so answering that question has to come first.

Comment: Not just how but why too. I think it would do some good to hear the reasons and motivations for his writing.

Comment: Why is it obvious, and how would this be interesting?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying a couple from the [Grammar Girl interview](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/grammar-girl-interview/):

- What exercise-related questions do you get most often from your
  listeners?
- What is the most interesting topic you've addressed lately?
- In your opinion, what is the most widespread misconception about
  working out and staying fit that people have?

Another interesting one from our site would be:

- [What are the pros and cons of walking versus running?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-running-versus-walking) I've read
  that running burns more calories than walking because of the energy
  it jumping from one foot to the other (moving up and down). But in
  Get Fit Guy's [post about it](http://getfitguy.quickanddirtytips.com/does-running-or-walking-burn-more-calories.aspx), he said that running burns more
  calories only after you finish, because of the need to pay back a
  greater oxygen debt. Doesn't the fact that you consume more oxygen
  while running mean you burn more calories during the activity too?
- [How many days should I work out per week](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/how-many-days-in-a-week-should-i-work-out)? I've read in many
  places that getting at least 30 minutes of exercise a day is
  important, but I've also read that it's important to take days off.
  Does it depend on the type of exercise you're doing, like the answer
  to our question says?