# What do we want to ask Nutrition Diva?

Tags: discussion, blog, site-promotion

We're going to be interviewing [Nutrition Diva](http://nutritiondiva.quickanddirtytips.com/) of [Quick and Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/) prior to being mentioned in her podcast. This will be happening pretty soon, so now we need some questions! The top-voted questions will be selected, and then a blog post will be made about the interview. The post will give her something interesting to refer his listeners to.

For ideas, check out this [English meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/what-are-we-going-to-ask-grammar-girl) where we did a similar thing with [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/). Feel free to suggest your favorite Fitness & Nutrition question that you'd like to get her take on!

Note - we are doing the same thing with [Get Fit Guy](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/what-do-we-want-to-ask-get-fit-guy) of Quick and Dirty Tips, but I'm asking for suggestions separately because they will be two separate interviews.

Answer (score 2):

1. Here is a good one from our site: [Where did the idea that we should
   eat three meals a day come from?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/where-did-the-idea-that-we-should-eat-three-times-a-day-come-from-under-what-au) What evidence is there to
   support that notion?
2. Also, I saw that she did a podcast on [Sweet vs. White Potatoes](http://nutritiondiva.quickanddirtytips.com/sweet-potatoes-versus-white-potatoes.aspx),
   so we could get her opinion on whether the accepted answer to [this
   question about potatoes](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/676/nutritional-difference-between-sweet-and-regular-potatoes) is correct.
3. What is your opinion on the intermittent fasting diet? Do you agree
   with the [top answer to our question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/592/experience-and-references-about-intermittent-fasting) about it?

Comment: I like to refer her to our questions, so that when we write the blog post up we'll get more click throughs to the actual site.

Comment: @IvoFlipse posted a [barrage of nutrition questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2274930#2274930) in chat (related to fitness) that we could consider asking too.

Answer (score 2):

- Why should I care about nutrition? Does it matter what I put into my body?
- What are some of the most common nutrition myths? Why does such misinformation exist?

  - Are there certain foods thought to be "bad" that are actually good?
  - Are there other foods that are definitely a no-no?
- We all know what's "wrong" for us and why we shouldn't eat certain things. What are the issues regarding why people do not change their nutritional habits?
- Should I go on a diet if I want to lose weight? How will the changes in my body affect me?
- What are the short-term and long-term effects of good and bad nutrition?